# Why is my cactus turning brown and getting crusty stuff on it?

Tags: cactus

[![brown base getting bigger ][1]][1]browning cactus- crusty near crown I have had these for about 5 or so years.  I noticed the brown near the bottom for quite some time but thought it was normal. This year I see yellow in the creases and some type of crusty stuff on the crown of one.  I don’t see any bugs, or black spots. It is kept outside in the summer and inside in the winter.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrxXq.jpg[image][image][image]

Comment: How long has it been in that pot? Is it cactus soil or regular potting soil? The brown spots higher on the big stem, is that fluffy stuff like cotton or is it hard/brittle? Sorry for the barrage of questions,  but the answers will provide clues.

Comment: It has been in the same pot for a couple of years in cactus soil.
I tried to loosen the soil a little and it was packed with roots.  I guess I need to repot it? But that scares me too, I don’t want to do it incorrectly.  As for the crusty stuff- it’s hard.